# F#/C#: How to import symbolic constants from library

Tags: c#, .net-core, f#, pinvoke

In order to use the ncurses library I have been using the following method:

```ml
[<Literal>]
let LIBNAME = "libncursesw.so.6"

[<DllImport(LIBNAME, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
extern unit initscr()
```

How do I extend this to work for symbolic constants such as the for the keys like `KEY_DOWN` and `KEY_UP`? Ideally I would like to be able to be able to use them in some kind of f# enum (discriminated or otherwise).

If there are better ways to do this in C# that would also be helpful!

Thank you!

Comment: Those constants are not present as objects in the library, they're just C/C++ constants, they get erased during compilation.

Comment: Ah ok, I guess i have to get those values from the header file? My main concern is how to make this more robust. So it doesn't rely on me entering all the correct values and so that it is robust to changes in the library

Comment: You could write a code generator that would consume the header files and spit out F# definitions, but there is no universal solution I'm afraid. But I think this is not as much of a problem in practice as you think: these values aren't going anywhere, they're already compiled into all the binaries that use the library, so changing them would be a major breakage.

Comment: You might be able to use swig here.  It can create a C# wrapper you can consume in your F# code. http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html

Comment: Practically any library has been ported to .NET, even the Unix ones.  .NETCore and Mono have been around long enough.  Visit nuget.org and type "ncurses" in the search box.  6 to choose from, all of them with source available.  That's going to save you a lot of time and effort.